# Switch background image with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have found similar questions and answers but afraid I am still a bit lost.  I just want a set of links that will addClass to the body to change the background image.  I only understand how to use the addClass property on the actual element being clicked, but I am not sure how to get that to add a class to another div.  Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the click event of the element, you can use any selector to manipulate the DOM.  In this case, I am attaching a click event to all the anchors on the page.  When any anchor is clicked, I am adding a class to the body element of the page.  The return false makes sure that the browser does not follow the href of the anchor.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("body").addClass("CLASS TO ADD");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. that seems like it should work but no go for me.. perhaps it is how I am using my CSS?

body {margin:0px;}
.class1{background: url(../images/sprays.jpg) repeat;}

   $("a.bd1").click(function(){
    $("body").addClass(".class1");
    return false;

<a class="bd1" href="#"><img src="images/box.gif"></a>

Comment: `addClass` takes a class name, not a CSS selector.  Remove the `.` from the call to `addClass` and it should work fine.

Comment: SLaks is right, you should use $("body").addClass("class1") without the period since it doesn't take a selector

Answer (score 3):

Using addClass()

```
$("#your_linkID").click(function(){
    $("#other_div").addClass("CLASS TO ADD");
});
```

or using [css()](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS) function

```
$("#selector_link").click( function(){
    $("#target_div").css({ 'background-image': 'url(/url-to-image.jpg)'});
});
```

Comment: The syntax of your css call is incorrect.  Either put backgroud-image in quotes or change it to backgroundImage.  Also, the url of the image needs to be wrapped with url() like "url('/url-to-image.jpg')"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

$("div").addClass("yourclassname");

Answer (score 1):

You can call the [`addClass`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/addClass#class) method on any jQuery object.

Therefore, you can use the `$` method to create a new jQuery object inside your event handler, like this:

```
$("a.bd1").click(function(e) {
    $("body").addClass("class1");
    return false;
});
```

For more information about how to select various elements using jQuery, read the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Note that `addClass` takes a class name, not a CSS selector, so you should add a `.` to its parameter.

Comment: great thanks.. i was adding a class like ".class1" rather than "class1" was my problem